# Speed up MSSQL to MySQL insert

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i have this that and it works fine but it takes 13 min to complete is there a way to speed this up.

```
insert into openquery(portal, 'select
  klient_id,
  smetka_br,
  smetka_datum,
  smetka_izdadena_datum,
  smetka_platena_datum,
  smetka_int_cena,
  smetka_tv_cena,
  smetka_dtv_cena,
  mesto_uplata,
    platena_tv,
    platena_int,
    platena_dtv,
    datum_tv,
    datum_int,
    datum_dtv from smetki_data_temp')
select
    a.klient_id, a.barcode, a.datum_valuta, a.promena_datum, b.datum_uplata, a.iznos_INT, a.iznos_KDS, a.iznos_DTV, a.zabeleska,
    a.platena_KDS, a.platena_INT, a.platena_DTV,
    (Cast(godina_KDS as VARCHAR) + '-' + Cast(mesec_KDS as VARCHAR) + '-01') as datum_tv,
    (Cast(godina_INT as VARCHAR) + '-' + Cast(mesec_INT as VARCHAR) + '-01') as datum_int,
    (Cast(godina_DTV as VARCHAR) + '-' + Cast(mesec_DTV as VARCHAR) + '-01') as datum_dtv
    from tSmetki as a
    INNER JOIN tUplati as b on b.smetka_id = a.id
    where a.barcode != ''
```

there are almost 2 mil rows. The select takes 30 sec to complete. Insert takes 12min.

```
   Affected rows: 1905280
    Time: 751.330s
```

Comment: Have you created index on tSmetki.Id and tUplati.smetka_id?

Comment: Is this a daily thing? Running this as a SQL job may increase your performance.

Comment: It's probably because you're doing it over a linked server (`portal` in your case). You could use something like SSIS or the Import/Export utility in SQL Server which should be able to make a number of optimizations. If that's not an option, you might consider batching it so you don't have a 2m row transaction going on across a linked server. I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to know what ETL tools they offer.

Comment: Give also information about your `INDEX columns` in this tables `openquery, tSmetki, tUplati`.

Comment: Adding 2 million rows to a table will always take a long time.  Not only are you adding records, but you might be updating indexes and/or checking referential integrity.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 2 million record rows taking 12 minutes, if have users waiting for process to complete, should them progress and let them know how they can notified (email, SMS, push) update completion

Comment: i have no INDEX colums on my openquery, indexes on tSmetki and tUplati should not be problem because selecting takes 30 sec or maybe im wrong i dont know.

Comment: Not really enough info to answer this. How fast is the `SELECT` statement itself just run on the server without throwing it at "portal"? How big is the data? What kind of connection are you using? Are the machines even in the same building? The same country? Last time I debugged something like this it turned out to be a faulty cable dropping what was meant to be gigabit Ethernet down to 100BaseT; there are lots of factors to investigate. (Without knowing anything else, 13 minutes for 2 million rows might actually be quite fast...)

Comment: Matt Gibson lol u give me the answer it was stupid network problem and i will fix :D tnx

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Dan Bracuk,  updating 2 million rows with INSERT builds indexes and checks constraints, and this can (and does) slow a lot.
My advice, just to ensure the strategy is correct, make a script that

- drop all indexes on inserted table
- executes the massive insert
- create indexes on inserted table

As a first step, don't tamper with constraints and don't touch anything else. See if there is an execution time improvement. Hope this helps.